# Google Cloud - Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to copy file from my local machine (Windows 10) to vm instance with this command :

```
gcloud compute scp --zone us-central1-a C:\Users\root\Downloads\***.sql ***-sandbox:~/var/www/html
```

I got this error

> Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key! Fatal:
>   Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server
>   sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) ERROR:
>   (gcloud.compute.scp) [C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk\pscp.exe] exited with return code [1].

I have try to delete .ssh folder at Application Data but still doesn't works.
Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to connect as `root`? What does `/var/log/auth.log` show? If you are trying to login as root, instead login as a normal user that has been added to the correct group with write permission for the directory.

Answer (score 0):

From windows machine to a linux you need to install [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_install)
The procedure is well explained [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#winscp).

Comment: Installing WinSCP is not required (but is a nice addition) - I use Bitvise. `gcloud` works well on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

how have you created the public/private key pair?
I used the "putty stack" and had similiar issues and have them fixed by

1. update "putty stack", at least: pageant and putty keygen to newest version ([https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html))
2. Create a new new key pair.
3. replace your old public key with the new one