# Sourcetree Update broke authentication

Tags: authentication, atlassian-sourcetree

I just updated from SourceTree 3.4.6 to 3.4.8 (Win 10) and now I can't access the remote repositories.
Any operation results in this msg:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks fetch --prune --tags origin
Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!
FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Luckily, I also have the GitExtensions tool installed, and it can still access my repos.
Why does updating SourceTree break my access?

Comment: Why the -1?  I couldn't find a SourceTree specific forum anywhere.

Comment: I had similiar issues: the solution I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413644/google-cloud-server-refused-public-key-signature-despite-accepting-key/72431594#72431594 helped me

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days, and several reboots it spontaneously started working again, with no changes to any settings.
So I have no clue as to why it wasn't working.